# ¿Qué debo poner antes del nombre, "C." o "Ing."?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, méxico, vocabulario-técnico, formalidad

Normalmente en mi contrato de prestación de servicios profesionales yo antecedo a mi nombre mi título universitario (Ing.). Sin embargo, un cliente me hizo notar que debería utilizar mejor C. (Como abreviatura de ciudadano) dado que el título universitario bien puede no ser válido en el supuesto que lo hubiera obtenido en otro país por ejemplo, en cambio ciudadano garantiza que tengo la capacidad de celebrar el contrato legalmente.

Tengo especificada mi nacionalidad en las declaraciones del contrato, así como el documento de identificación que me habilita como ciudadano. Pero de acuerdo a lo comentado por mi cliente posiblemente debería anteponer a mi nombre: "C. Ing.". ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta o en su defecto la más adecuada?

Mi región es México Central. Y ciertamente al menos en el centro de México las personas anteceden su título académico a su nombre. Por ejemplo Ing. Juan Carlos, Arq. Laura, Lic. Sandoval.

Comment: Interesante pregunta. Dado que etiquetas con "diferencias-regionales", ¿podrías indicar en qué región te está ocurriendo esto? Por ejemplo en España yo nunca pondría "Ing." antes de mi nombre, pero he visto que en algunos países de Hispanoamérica se usa abundantemente.

Comment: ... y contrario a España (según el comentario de @fedorqui) en Colombia usarías Ing. pero nunca C.

Comment: En Argentina todo va con título prepuesto: "Dr.", "Ing.", "Lic.", "Mgr.", etc. Un poco presuntuoso cuando no se trata de escritos formales o no tienen relación con la expertise del profesional en cuestión. Lo de "C." es una novedad para mí.

Comment: En el supuesto de que el título sea extranjero, se debe hacer un trámite de revalidación y obtener la cédula profesional. En México puede ser ilegal ejercer una profesión sin este requisito. Para este tipo de dudas, recomendaría consultar un abogado.

Answer (score 1):

**Ing**. sin lugar a dudas.

Eso de C es una política extraña de tu contratador y no es algo usado globalmente.

Jamás quites importancia al título que seguramente te ha costado tanto lograr.

Answer (score 1):

La letra "C" escrita antes del nombre, mas bien se escribe por carecer de un título universitario (*Ciudadano/a*), pero no debe ser sinónimo de menor capacidad en el cargo que se desempeña, hay casos donde personas sin título han demostrado ser mas capaces que las tituladas, pero sin menospreciar que un título universitario adquirido con mérito es de gran ayuda para el cargo a desempeñar, ya sea en el sector privado o público.

Esto es para el área de Guadalajara, México, año 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Para el caso específico de México y de un contrato de servicios, asumiendo que los servicios se relacionan con la ingeniería en cuestión; el uso mas común es solamente **Ing.** << Nombre >>. En caso de que los servicios no estén relacionados, depende de la situación y puede haber casos en que es mejor anteponer **C.** al nombre y omitir **Ing.** Lo mismo sucede con otros títulos académicos como **Dr.**, **Lic.**, **Arq.**, etc.

La forma correcta, si quisieras usar ambos, sería **C. Ing.** << Nombre >>. El tratamiento de  ciudadano es un privilegio mayor, es decir, confiere derechos generales; en tanto que el título de ingeniero añade derechos específicos. Sin embargo, el uso de **C. Ing.** puede resultar presuntuoso para algunas personas.

En la correspondencia de las instituciones de gobierno, existen fórmulas estrictas mas o menos homologadas. Por el contrario, en las empresas privadas, las formas son mas variables y dependen de la política interna. Algunas instruyen omitir todo tipo de tratamiento y prefieren el uso del nombre sin prefijos o sufijos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto sería: C. Ing. Pepito Pérez Pérez ó por lo menos en derecho así es:
C. JUEZ TRIGÉSIMO SEXTO DE LO FAMILIAR, C. Lic. Fulanito Pérez Pérez, C. Presidente Constitucional de los Estados Unidos Mexicanos Lic. Andrés Manuel López Obrador. Te comparto este link: http://www.cambio.gob.mx/IMG/pdf/carta_presidente_29-10-20_con_firmas.pdf

Comment: Bienvenido al stack. Podrías explicar porqué esa forma es la correcta? Hay alguna regla detrás de ella? Gracias.